# The best scoring REVOLVER

Tags: word, pattern, optimization, chess

The initial setup a chess game creates this layout:

```
P P P P P P P P
R N B Q K B N R
```

If we change the symbol each piece is represented by, something interesting occurs.

```
* * * * * * * * 
R E V O L V E R
```

The lower half creates a valid English word, if knights are represented by the letter e, bishops by v, queen by o, and king by l.

Using the system A = 1, B = 2, etc. what are the lowest and highest possible scores that follow this system? A word is "valid" if found in a major dictionary, be it Webster, Oxford, variants thereof, etc.

Comment: what's a "score"?

Comment: @TonyEnnis The cumulative total of the score of each letter used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found

> **DRAWCARD** with score 72
>  **REVOLVER** has score 117
>
>  Listed in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drawcard), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drawcard), [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/drawcard), [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Drawcard) and [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/drawcard)
>
>  Admittedly it's a bit 'fringe', but it sits well with REVOLVER and *games*.
>
>  *<sup>by my own hand :)</sup>*

Comment: I could not improve on another answer's highest-scoring.

Answer (score 8):

I found these ones with help from [Qat](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=01234210&ent=Search&dict=0):

> marigram = 13+1+18+9+7+18+1+13 = 80

> despised = 4+5+19+16+9+19+5+4 = 81

> devolved = 4+5+22+15+12+22+5+4 = 89

> evincive = 5+22+9+14+3+9+22+5 = 89

> marjoram = 13+1+18+10+15+18+1+13 = 89

> detorted = 4+5+20+15+18+20+5+4 = 91

> minyanim = 13+9+14+25+1+14+9+13 = 98

> renowner = 18+5+14+15+23+14+5+18 = 112

> revolver = 18+5+22+15+12+22+5+18 = 117

> sterlets = 19+20+5+18+12+5+20+19 = 118